# Close tab after returning with to app

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, box-api

I'm implementing an app that uses the box-api on iOS 6.1.

The app calls out to mobile safari and on it's return the login page on Box remains open. what I would like to do is after the login and token has been received to tell mobile safari to close the tab.

Comment: @H2CO3 does that mean to your knowledge it's not possible?

Answer (score 1):

We accomplish this for a web application using the API v1 auth, so you can try doing the same thing on iOS to see if it works.

Basically if you go to edit your application, there is a section called 'Backend parameters:' with an option 'Redirect url:'.  We have our Redirect url set to a webpage that has the following script:

```
<script>window.close();</script>
```

This will close the window when the user gets redirected to that page following the authentication process.  Note that this javascript command will only work on a window that has been opened by javascript, so if you manually navigate to the window in your browser it *will not* close.  I'm not sure what the behaviour with a tab opened in mobile safari will be.